# How to count number of branches in Java class

Tags: java

Is there a tool or a way to count the number of branches in a given Java class? For example, I want to count the number of branches in the following simple Java class:

```
public class Testt {

    public boolean getTest(int x) {
        if (x > 5) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public int getTest1(int x) {
        int t = 0;
        if (x == 10) {
            t = 1;
        } else if (x == 8) {
            t = 3;
        } else {
            t = 11;
        }
        return t;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why? What do to want to achieve? Do you have a bigger piece of code where you want to run that on? In example like that, you don't need any tool, you should be able to just see that it's `2` and `3` respectively.

Comment: @JaroslawPawlak I have a class of thousands of lines and so many branches, this is why I want to the number of branches.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The term you are looking for is "[cyclomatic complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclomatic_complexity)".

> Cyclomatic complexity is a software metric (measurement), used to
>   indicate the complexity of a program. It is a quantitative measure of
>   the number of linearly independent paths through a program's source
>   code.

If you are using Eclipse as your IDE there is a plugin called Eclipse Metrics that can give this kind of information.